# Sloping lawn with bad drainage

Tags: lawn

I have a small new build site lawn that is approx 5M x 3m sloping from 0 to 450mm. It is heavy clay soil that I want to level off, meaning I will have to build up 450mm. I am putting perforated drainage pipe on three sides to improve the drainage with outlet to a storm-water drain. I want to lawn the area with borders for flowers. What is the best way / combination of topsoil / aggregate / compost to make this level?

Comment: pictures and drawings help

Comment: you can dig out the basement and use that dirt on the sides of the house then pack the dirt.

Comment: I am building up the area and need to fill to 450mm. I wanted to know what the best combination of hardcore to soil ratio to use (ie 250mm hardcore then 200mm of topsoil) to fill up to that level for the best drainage option.